# Copying random unique rows from 1 sheet to another in VBA based on multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to randomly copy 70 rows from a sheet called "Master" and copy those 70 rows into a sheet called "Checks" based on column S being "FTF" and the random split needs to be 65 where column AT = "ASL" and 5 where column AT = "Customer". I need the copied rows to meet the above criteria but also be unique so if it tries to copy across the same row twice it will skip it.

The "Master" sheet has columns all the way up to BR but I only want t copy across columns starting at P and ending at BR.

The code I have so far which seems to be copying across 70 values is below but it brings over all rows irrespective of what's in column S and that's the additional criteria I need:

```
Sub MattWilliams()

Dim rawDataWs As Worksheet, randomSampleWs As Worksheet
Dim map, i As Long, n As Long, c As Long, rand, col
Dim rng As Range
Dim keyArr, nRowsArr

Set rawDataWs = Worksheets("Master")
Set randomSampleWs = Worksheets("Checks")

randomSampleWs.UsedRange.ClearContents

'EDIT: dynamic range in ColA
Set rng = rawDataWs.Range("AT9:AT" & rawDataWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

Set map = RowMap(rng)

keyArr = Array("ALS", "Customer") '<== keywords
nRowsArr = Array(65, 5) '<== # of random rows

Debug.Print "Key", "#", "Row#"
For i = LBound(keyArr) To UBound(keyArr)
    If map.exists(keyArr(i)) Then

        Set col = map(keyArr(i))
        n = nRowsArr(i)

        For c = 1 To n
            'select a random member of the collection
            rand = Application.Evaluate("RANDBETWEEN(1," & col.Count & ")")
            Debug.Print keyArr(i), rand, col(rand)
            rawDataWs.Rows(col(rand)).Copy _
                 randomSampleWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            'col.Remove rand 'remove the "used" row
            If col.Count = 0 Then
                If c < n Then Debug.Print "Not enough rows for " & keyArr(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c

    Else
        Debug.Print "No rows for " & keyArr(i)
    End If
Next i
End Sub

'get a map of rows as a dictionary where each value is a collection of row  numbers
Function RowMap(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim dict, c As Range, k
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        k = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(k) > 0 Then
            If Not dict.exists(k) Then dict.Add k, New Collection
            dict(k).Add c.Row
        End If
    Next c
    Set RowMap = dict
End Function
```

I need some help amending the above code to only copy across rows based on my criteria but i'm struggling to understand how to amend the code.

Thanks for any help with just trying to know where i'm going wrong or how I can work out how to amend VBA code as above. I've tried searching on the forums but nothing is quite what i'm looking for or helps me identify where i'm going wrong.

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Here's the complete code. Disregard my previously posted answer...just had to make a small change to the RowMap function (also changed some variable names, hope its not a big deal)

```
Option Explicit

Sub MattWilliams()

    Dim rawDataWs As Worksheet, randomSampleWs As Worksheet
    Dim map, i As Long, n As Long, counter As Long, rand, col
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim keyArr, nRowsArr

    Set rawDataWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    Set randomSampleWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Checks")

    randomSampleWs.UsedRange.ClearContents

    'EDIT: dynamic range in ColA
    Set rng = rawDataWs.Range("AT9:AT" & rawDataWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    Set map = RowMap(rng, rawDataWs)

    keyArr = Array("ALS", "Customer") '<== keywords
    nRowsArr = Array(65, 5) '<== # of random rows

    Debug.Print "Key", "#", "Row#"
    For i = LBound(keyArr) To UBound(keyArr)
        If map.exists(keyArr(i)) Then

            Set col = map(keyArr(i))
            n = nRowsArr(i)

            For counter = 1 To n
                'select a random member of the collection
                rand = Application.Evaluate("RANDBETWEEN(1," & col.Count & ")")
                Debug.Print keyArr(i), rand, col(rand)
                rawDataWs.Rows(col(rand)).Copy _
                     randomSampleWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                col.Remove rand 'remove the "used" row
                If col.Count = 0 Then
                    If counter < n Then Debug.Print "Not enough rows for " & keyArr(i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next counter

        Else
            Debug.Print "No rows for " & keyArr(i)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

'get a map of rows as a dictionary where each value is a collection of row  numbers
Function RowMap(rng As Range, rawDataWs As Worksheet) As Object

    Dim dict, cell As Range, cellValue

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    ' "ALS" or "Customer"
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        cellValue = Trim(cell.Value)
        If Len(cellValue) > 0 Then
            If (Not dict.exists(cellValue)) And rawDataWs.Range("S" & cell.Row).Value = "FTF" Then
                dict.Add cellValue, New Collection
                dict(cellValue).Add cell.Row
            ElseIf rawDataWs.Range("S" & cell.Row).Value = "FTF" Then
                dict(cellValue).Add cell.Row
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    Set RowMap = dict

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried the above and it seems to be copying across 70 but then if it selects two rows that are the same it's not picking another number so I need to figure that bit out. It seems to only be picking rows where the conditions are met though which is progress so thank you again.

Comment: I edited the code in the answer and changed `Exit For` to `c = c - 1` ...let me know if that helps

Comment: Still doing the same really. It's copying across 70 rows which is what I want but there's still some duplicate rows being copied across. In the debug print it seems to have more than the 70 rows but only 70 are being copied across. Any suggestions? I pasted your edited code over my own. It's an improvement as i'm at least getting 70 copied across. I've read that unique:=True can be used in VBA but not sure if that's applicable here?

Comment: Have you had any more ideas about how to copy across only unique values ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, really do appreciate it. I've had a look at loads of resources and I can't find anything quite what i'm looking for. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciate it. I'll test this when I get 10 minutes later on tonight and upvote your answer

Comment: Works an absolute treat. Thank you very much. I've never used the Map function so I'll take some time to learn how it can be used as it seems quite powerful. Should be able to utilise it in other spreadsheets in the future.